# GDAL installation in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, gis

Has anybody been able to overcome this issue while installing GDAL in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS or should I just downgrade my Ubuntu version?

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable

Err:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done                      
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Thanks, but that did not work. It keeps giving me the same error `E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.`.

Comment: What of "*The PPA you've added does not support your version of Ubuntu*" don't you understand? It will not work for 20.04. Maybe later, but not now. But why would you need a PPA for `gdal` anyways? The PPA has version 3.0.4 for 18.04, [20.04 has 3.0.4](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/gdal) in [universe repo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository). Simply install from there without the ppa.